# /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp and acpitz-virtual-0 repoorted by lm-sensors not changing

Tags: temperature, sensors

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.3. `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`, `acpitz-virtual-0` from `lm-sensors` and `acpi -t` give the same incorrect results. 27 for `thermal 0` and 29 for `thermal 1` and they are not changing. My motherboard is Gigabyte B85M-D3V-A. Could this be something mis configured or simply the kernel doesn't support my motherboard?

Update: CPUID's HWmonitor gives the same result for `tz0` and `tz1`. So it's not just Linux. There might be something wrong with my motherboard?

Comment: I'm having similar problems, except I have `tz2` reporting correct temp of **78C** whilst `tz0` as **27.8C** and `tz1` has **29.8C**. I'm delving into systemd fancontrol service, sensors-detect, i8kmon, dell_smm and some acpi stuff. As this is over a year old I wonder what is new? I don't recall problems with Ubuntu 14.04.1 but have had noticed lots since 16.04.1.

Comment: I have two 14.04.5 systems (using different brands of hardware) on both of them the `sensors` command always report the same temperatures for `acpitz-virtual-0`. The temperatures I get are always `+27.8°C` and `+29.8°C`. So it seems a widespread problem.